# Why are FGLS standard errors so low when estimating linear regression on panel data?

Tags: panel-data, standard-error, fixed-effects-model, clustered-standard-errors, robust-standard-error

I am currently writing my master thesis an the effect of academic publication on anomaly returns. The idea is that in finance literature anomaly - factors/portfolios are proposed. After the factor is published in a journal the time series of the returns of the factor, which was positive before, decreases significantly.

I estimate a fixed effect regression model using panel data of factor returns to study this effect.

The data is structured as follows:
My data set consists of about 207 factors. For each "factor/portfolio" I have a time series of monthly returns e.g.from 01.01.1990 until 31.12.2021. The length of the time series is not equal across the factors. Each factor has a dummy variable for each point in time that is one if the observation is after the sample considered in the publication otherwise it is zero. Similarly, each factor has a dummy variable for each point in time that is one if the observation is after the publication in the journal otherwise it is zero

The model is defined as:

$$ \label{regression_model}
R_{i,t} = \alpha_{i} + \beta_{1} S_{i,t} + \beta_{2} P_{i,t} + \epsilon_{i,t}
$$

where $R_{i,t}$ is the return of factor $i$ at time $t$, $\alpha_{i}$ estimates the predictors fixed effect. $S_{i,t}$ is the post-sample dummy variable and $P_{i,t}$ is the post-publication dummy.

In the literature it is proposed to either use:

- (i) heteroscedasticity-consistent standard errors
- (ii) standard errors estimated by clustering on time
- (iii) standard errors estimated using a FGLS method under the assumption of contemporaneous cross-sectional correlation between panel portfolio residuals

I estimated an FGLS Model since it was considered to be the most conservative by the literature. To do so I used the `plm`  R package and the following model:

```r
model_fgls <- pggls(ret ~ out_samp + post_pub, data=pred_ret, 
                model="within", index=c("signalname"), 
                effect="individual")
```

```r
Oneway (individual) effect Within FGLS model

Call:
pggls(formula = ret ~ out_samp + post_pub, data = pred_ret, 
    effect = "individual", 
    model = "within", index = c("signalname"))

Unbalanced Panel: n = 207, T = 197-1146, N = 126463

Residuals:
        Min.      1st Qu.       Median      3rd Qu.         Max. 
-16.97522740  -1.61125401  -0.04535875   1.54106692  16.57735040 

Coefficients:
            Estimate  Std. Error z-value  Pr(>|z|)    
out_samp -0.20112934  0.00092318 -217.87 < 2.2e-16 ***
post_pub -0.32183118  0.00038256 -841.25 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Total Sum of Squares: 1691500
Residual Sum of Squares: 1667300
Multiple R-squared: 0.0143
```

However, the results are confusing since the standard erros are much lower compared to the literature and other methods I tested.

Here is the same model but estimated using estimatr: robust standard errors clustering on month (ym).

```r
model_robust <- lm_robust(ret ~ out_samp + post_pub, 
         fixed_effects=~signalname, clusters=ym, data=pred_ret)
```

```r
Call:
lm_robust(formula = ret ~ out_samp + post_pub, data = pred_ret, 
    clusters = ym, fixed_effects = ~signalname)

Standard error type:  CR2 

Coefficients:
         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|) CI Lower CI Upper    DF
out_samp  -0.1936    0.06211  -3.117 1.99e-03  -0.3158 -0.07142 320.4
post_pub  -0.3294    0.05237  -6.289 6.87e-10  -0.4323 -0.22648 509.7

Multiple R-squared:  0.0143 ,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.01268
Multiple R-squared (proj. model):  0.001559 ,   Adjusted R-squared (proj. model):  -8.547e-05 
F-statistic (proj. model): 20.11 on 2 and 1145 DF,  p-value: 2.611e-09
```

Similarly using plm and correcting standard errors using vcovBK by  Beck and Katz.

```r
model_95_vcovHC <- plm(ret ~ out_samp + post_pub, data=pred_ret, 
    model="within", index=c("signalname"),effect="individual")

coeftest(model_95_vcovHC, vcov=function(x) plm::vcovBK(x, 
            cluster = 'time', type='HC3'))
```

```r
t test of coefficients:

          Estimate Std. Error  t value  Pr(>|t|)    
out_samp -0.193602   0.042276  -4.5795 4.666e-06 ***
post_pub -0.329367   0.031385 -10.4944 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The estimated coefficients are similar across all methods. FGLS, however, yields standard deviations of 0.00092318 and 0.00038256 compared to 0.042276 and 0.031385 which is the same order of magnitude reported in the literature.

My questions therefore are:

- Why are the standard error of the FGLS model so low?
- Did I specify the model wrong or is this common?
- Which method should I use?